# How to Give action to the tab bar item

Tags: iphone

This is my code for my tab bar

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Crops ", @"Articles");

    UITabBar *tabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 376, 320, 44)];
    item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"TypesToTry" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"crops.png"] tag:0];
    item2  = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"WhenToPlant" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"crops.png"] tag:1];

    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1,item2,item3,item4,item5, nil];
    [tabBar setItems:items animated:YES];
    [tabBar setSelectedItem:nil];
    tabBar.delegate=self;

    [self.view addSubview:tabBar];
 }
```

what i want is whenever i tap on the 1st tab i want to go to that particular description ,so where to right this action.Please help me in this.
The questions may be simple,but for me they are difficult :),Please help this new developer

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i think you can add following line of code to make your tab bar item workable

```
[item1 performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(Yourfunction) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

[item2 performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(Yourfunction) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

put this line at end of -(void) didLoad, i hope it will work for you